# Font Identification - Recent Starbucks Ad

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif, script

I was  wondering if someone could tell me what font this is? This was a coupon Starbucks sent out a few weeks ago for the Caramel Flan Latte. I'm looking for the "Let's Get Together" lettering. Thanks!

[image: starbucks ad]

Comment: carrrrrapaccino of course!!! :)

Comment: you can try to use [http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) this does not search all foundries but sometimes the results pretty good sometimes they are less than perfect.

Answer (score 5):

That is **Estilo Script** by DSType: http://www.dstype.com/fonts/estilo-script